# How to set up webpack with css modules

Tags: html, css, reactjs, module, webpack

I'm trying to configure my webpack with css modules, but it's not working.

my webpack is like this:

```
module: {
 rules: [
   {
     test: /\.s?css$/,
     include: path.resolve(__dirname, './assets/css-master/'),
     loader: extractSass.extract({
       use: [
         // { loader: 'css-loader' },
         { loader: 'css-loader?modules&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]' },
         { loader: 'sass-loader' },
       ],
       // use style-loader in development
       fallback: 'style-loader',
     }),
     exclude: /node_modules/,
   },
 ],
},
```

When I call for className="test" it returns me the css, but when className={cssImported.test} is called, it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem uninstalling react-css-modules and I changed the loader. Now it looks like this (just the 's' was removed from module's'):`{ loader: 'css-loader?module&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]' },`